# Visual Studio 2013 - C# - IHttpActionResult cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

Trying to build the test project below, I get this error:

> Error: The type or namespace name 'IHttpActionResult' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In the "Reference Manager" dialog, Assemblies/Framework, I ticked the System.Web.Http box.

Here is the source:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace dotNET45_test
{
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) { }
    }

    class Test : IHttpActionResult {   // <-- Error
    }
}
```

Is anything missing in the source code, or in the project settings?

Comment: You have to reference the [web api nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853196/the-type-or-namespace-ihttpactionresult-not-found similar

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853196/the-type-or-namespace-ihttpactionresult-not-found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type or namespace IHttpActionResult not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853196/the-type-or-namespace-ihttpactionresult-not-found)